# Is the Enforce Signed Header required when calling the POST request?

Tags: java, android, http-headers, instagram

When creating my Android App I was struggling to like photo's on my feed, if I remember it correctly, the solution was to provide a Enforce Signed Header when creating the instagram object. However if I take a look in the API documentation it says:

> Important Note Your Client Secret should be kept secure at all times.
>   Do not share this Secret with anyone, do not include it in java-script
>   code or a mobile client. **Mobile apps that do not have a server-side
>   component should not use the Enforce signed header setting.** You have
>   the ability to reset your Client Secret to a new value at any time, if
>   you suspect that it was leaked.

But, when I had the Enforce Signed Header disabled, the likes didn't work. When using the Enforce Signed Header, I am providing the remote IP of the device trough http://myip.dnsomatic.com/ with a HTTP Request to parse the webpage.

Again a quote from the dev API:

> The following endpoints require the X-Insta-Forwarded-For header if Enforce signed header is enabled:
>
> - POST /users/{user_id}/relationship
> - POST /media/{media_id}/comments
> - DEL /media/{media_id}/comments/{comment_id}
> - POST  /media/{media_id}/likes
> - DEL /media/{media_id}/likes

So basically it says (well what I get from this quote) is that these endpoints require the X-Insta-Forwarded-For header IF the Enforce Signed Header is enabled. So is means that they don't require that header if the Enforce Signed Header is disabled.

Am I doing this right, or am I able to like photo's and video's without the Enforce Signed Header?

I'll edit this and post a log when trying to like a photo without the Enforce Signed Header later today. Thanks!

Another quick question, in the quote of the docs above, they say to not include the Client Secret in the code, but the Client Secret is required to create an instagram object. How are you solving this challenge? Right now I got the client secret stored in an encrypted key in my app, is this a good way?

Thanks for all your tips,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u dont use Enforce Signed Header (and X-Insta-Forwarded-For), then u can still like, comment and follow/unfollow, but you will have lower limit for liking/hour or follow/hour.

Check this page for limits when using signed call vs unsigned calls:
http://instagram.com/developer/limits/

Comment: The API says I'm not allowed to use it at the mobile side. are there any advantages besides the limit raise to use Enfore Signed Headers?

Comment: the code for signing header should not be in mobile client code, since it requires the client_secret to be in code, you can still implement in server code and your app can call the server side. Another advantage of using signed header is that instagram can block anyone who is spamming using your  app.

Comment: So you recommend getting servers to handle the requests?

Comment: it depends if u need the extra limit, if u dont then you can do all app side to start with and then move to server if u really want to, it is good to have no server dependency, one less thing to worry about.

Comment: I'll monitor the usage of the app once it launches, if many users are reaching the limit I'll extend my service with servers! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong the Enforce Signed Header is not required to use the post request on instagram. Clean logcat when using my app.

Thanks!